# Create a executable for a scheme program with arguments

Tags: scheme, executable, racket

I have a scheme program which is executed using the command ; (primes<= n) gives me all the primes less than n ; (primes<= 200) gives me all the primes less than 200

How do I create an executable in linux for the program below taking n as an argument

```
---------Scheme Program------------------------------------------------

    #lang racket

(define  (interval-list m n)
  (if (> m n)
      '()
      (cons m (interval-list (+ 1 m) n))))
(define (sieve l)
  (define (remove-multiples n l)
    (if (null? l)
         '()
         (if  (= (modulo (car l) n) 0)      ; division test
              (remove-multiples n (cdr l))
              (cons (car l)
                    (remove-multiples n (cdr l))))))
  (if (null? l)
      '()
      (cons (car l)
             (sieve (remove-multiples (car l) (cdr l))))))
(define (primes<= n)
  (sieve (interval-list 2 n)))
```

The above program is executed as (primes<= 100)prints all the primes less than 100

Answer (score 1):

It appears you are using Racket, so you should follow [these instructions](http://docs.racket-lang.org/drracket/create-exe.html) to create your executable. In general, each Scheme system provides its own method to create an executable, so you will have to read the documents that come with your system.

You might enjoy this alternate implementation of the Sieve of Eratosthenes:

```
(define (primes n) ; sieve of eratosthenes
  (let ((ps (list)) (sieve (make-vector (+ n 1) #t)))
    (do ((p 2 (+ p 1))) ((< n p) (reverse ps))
      (when (vector-ref sieve p)
        (set! ps (cons p ps))
        (do ((i (* p p) (+ i p))) ((< n i))
          (vector-set! sieve i #f))))))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can turn a Racket module into a unix-style script by inserting

```
#! /usr/bin/env racket
```

(if racket is in your search path) at the top and making it executable (`chmod`).

See the [docs for creating unix-style scripts](http://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/scripts.html) for more details.